# Can't fix parsing error for new dropdown menu

Tags: parsing, circleci

I got this error when I wanted to add another menu to my drop-down menu.
I am not sure why this error came up. 
I added `dropdown.avatar.` because that what other menus also had. But it didn't work. What could I be missing here?

circle CI said it's a `33:41  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token`

```
  31 |         <Link route="/stats">
  32 |           <a>
> 33 |             <Icon type="profile" /> {{t("dropdown.avatar.viewMoreStats")}}
     |                                         ^
  34 |           </a>
  35 |         </Link>
  36 |       </li>
```